# how to define a html folder to make it work with WordPress commands

Tags: plugins, functions, wp-load.php

so is it possible to define a folder outside the wp-$folders ?

i created a html page and i want to use WordPress hooks and filters in it simply the WordPress PHP syntax

im still learning php - and i dont know what file should i call to make it work

**my wordpress file system looks like**

```
wordpress 
|
|
|_ helloworld _ index.php ( contain php code + html - js - css )
|_ wp-admin
|_ wp-content
|_ wp-includes
normal WordPress file system
..
.
```

i want the index.php that inside the hello word (dir) to make it able to run WordPress commands and not be just static page

*Note : i dont want to turn the html into a template (:**

Comment: Note that loading WordPress into another file like this is fragile and has security consequences. People will suggest using a template because it's the right thing to do, and what you want to do is considered very bad practice and a common mistake of people new to WordPress and PHP.

Comment: got it thanks for replying